# Cannot read properties of undefined (service)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a html file from which I call the function.The error is at this.resultsService calling inside results.component.ts. I tried the calling using () => but it doesn't call my function at all. I am not sure what is wrong here.

html file :

```
<ng-template
      [customFunction]="functionExample()"
    >
```

error in this component on line  this.resultsService
results.components.ts

```
import { ResultsService} from "../../services/results.service";
export class ResultsComponent extends ClassTable
{
 constructor(
    private resultsService: ResultsService
  ) {
    super(injector);
  }

 functionExample(){

    this.resultsService
           .fetchData(
             this.criteria
           )
           .subscribe(
             //do a bunch of things
           );
    } 
}
```

results-service.ts :

```
 public fetchData(
    criteria: any): Observable<any> {
     let url = `http://localhost:8080/v1/alldata`;
    return this.httpClient.post(url, criteria, {
      headers: {
        "x-url-token": token && token !== null ? token.appURLToken : ""
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re doing here (and why). Where are you actually calling that function and how? Also, on what line does this error occur? Not seeing a ‘service’ here?

Comment: @MikeOne: calling the function to get some results on click of a custom link from html code. the functionExample calls the method fetchData in resultsService.ts and fetches the data from server url and renders it. I get an error when I call  this.resultsService inside functionExample()

Comment: Please post some more code or a simplified (functional) example. Your problem is probably related to ‘this’ context, but there is not enough here to determine. Can’t even see where the error is at the moment?

Comment: @MikeOne : simplified the code to only put relevant details. I get the error in results.component.ts on calling this.resultsService.fetchData

Comment: Right. So this is probably not going to work. I suspect that ‘this’ is lost (it will be the context of the calling station, not of the actual component you’re calling). This setup is really never needed (and it’s not good practice  in the first place). What are you actually trying to solve with this?

Comment: I am trying to call that service on click of a link (which is a reusable component) on the template in html. (exists and I don't have control to change this)  i need to get the data from the results service in a custom function (functionExample) and download to an excel. Is there a different way to call the service function ?

Comment: Yes..? Use a service, not a component? Or fire an event from the child component to the parent and let the parent deal with it.

Comment: Thanks. I am unable to directly call the service without going through the component because of an existing setup. Will check the second option

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function from the template HTML, you need to use parenthesis

```html
<ng-template [customFunction]="functionExample()" >
...
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, check if your service is been provided in `root`

```js
@Injectable({ provideIn: 'root' })
export class YourService {...}
```

If it's not provided as root, either add that data to your service metadata or, specify it in the `providers` array of its current module, for example, `app.module.ts`:

```js
@NgModule({
 ...,
 providers: [YourService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```